# Angular Google Cloud Firebase Auth Custom claims issue with lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angular-routing, angularfire

I currently am using **Google Cloud Functions, Google Authentication** and **Angular** version 12.1.4.

**Packages**

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1201.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.1.4
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@nguniversal/builders           12.1.0
@nguniversal/express-engine     12.1.0
@schematics/angular             12.1.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

I am using Angular Fire **Custom Claims** to set the user permissions to claim for admin, content creator, and registered.

This appears to work on all routes but the root admin route of my lazy loaded route. Currently, I removed the **authguard** from the admin route and the child routes work - but if I add the **authguard** to the parent the admin route - the routing produces no console errors but just redirects to the absolute root route / and doesn't even redirect to welcome - as though it just decides to stop.  it draws a blank page and that's it. everywhere else where the routes have the **authguards** applied work fine.

**Lazy Loaded Admin Module**

```
const adminRoutes:Routes =[
  {path:'', component: AdminDashboardComponent},
  {path:'content', component:ContentComponent},
  {path:'content/edit/:id', component:EditComponent},
  {path:'**', redirectTo: 'admin'}
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    ContentComponent,
    EditComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)
  
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule],
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, customClaims, redirectLoggedInTo, redirectUnauthorizedTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const contenteditor = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.roles === 'contenteditor'));
const registered = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.roles === 'registered'));
const admin = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.roles === 'admins'));
const redirectLoggedInToProfile = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['profile']);
const redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['welcome']);

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'welcome', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'welcome', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/splash/splash.module').then(m=>m.SplashModule)},
  {path:'admin', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule)},

  {path:'admin/content', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: admin || contenteditor, redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome}},
  {path:'admin/content/edit/:id', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: admin || contenteditor, redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome}},

  {path:'dashboard', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m=>m.DashboardModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: admin || contenteditor || registered, redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome}},
```

**Google Cloud Function Helper** that's invoked to set the custom claim.

```
export function CustomClaimsHelper(id:string){
    const coll = 'users'
    var docRef = db.collection(`${coll}`).doc(`${id}`);

    docRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
           const role = doc.data()?.roles;
           console.log('RULE')
           if(role.admin===true){
               const admin = role.admin;
               const customClaims = {
                admin: true,
              };
              const setclaim =  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(id, customClaims)
            //    console.log('ADMINCLAIM', admin.auth().getCustomUserClaims(id))
              setclaim.then((result: any) =>{ return result})
           } 
           if(role.contenteditor===true){
            const customClaims = {
                contenteditor: true,
              };
             const setclaim =  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(id, customClaims)
            //    console.log('ADMINCLAIM', admin.auth().getCustomUserClaims(id))
              setclaim.then((result) =>{ return result})
           }
           if(role.registered===true){
            const customClaims = {
                registered: true,
              };
   const setclaim =  admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(id, customClaims)
            //    console.log('ADMINCLAIM', admin.auth().getCustomUserClaims(id))
              setclaim.then((result) =>{ return result})            }

            // console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        errorHandlerHelper(error)
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1):

How I fixed it - one has to return the user object - in order to set the claim - and then I adjusted my app-router.module.

in case someone else runs into his with google cloud functions or angular auth.

**Google Cloud Function**

```
export const Claim = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
  const userId = context?.auth?.token?.uid as string;
        const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId);

      //  addDocHelper()

      docRef.get().then(async (doc) => {
           const role = doc.data()?.roles;
           console.log('RULE', role)
               const customClaims = {
                    role              
                };
              console.log('ADMin',customClaims)
           await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, customClaims).then(() => {
            //Interesting to note: we need to re-fetch the userRecord, as the user variable **does not** hold the claim
            return admin.auth().getUser(userId);
       })    
  });})
```

**app-routing.module client**

```
const contenteditor = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims?.role?.contenteditor === true));
const registered = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims?.role?.registered  === true));
const admincheck = () => pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims?.role?.admin === true));


const redirectLoggedInToProfile = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['profile']);
const redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['welcome']);

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'welcome', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'welcome', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/splash/splash.module').then(m=>m.SplashModule)},
  {path:'admin', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule), canActivate:[AngularFireAuthGuard]},

  {path:'admin/content', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: admincheck || contenteditor, redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome}},
  {path:'admin/content/edit/:id', loadChildren:()=>import('./routes/admin/admin.module').then(m=>m.AdminModule), canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: admincheck || contenteditor, redirectUnauthorizedToWelcome}},
```